# Enabling Classes for Use with boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

Code snippet from [lexical_cast](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544):

```
class lexical_castable {
public:
  lexical_castable() {};
  lexical_castable(const std::string s) : s_(s) {};

  friend std::ostream operator<<
    (std::ostream& o, const lexical_castable& le);
  friend std::istream operator>>
    (std::istream& i, lexical_castable& le);

private:
  virtual void print_(std::ostream& o) const {
    o << s_ <<"\n";
  }

  virtual void read_(std::istream& i) const {
    i >> s_;
  }

  std::string s_;
};

std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& o,
  const lexical_castable& le) {
  le.print_(o);
  return o;
}

std::istream operator>>(std::istream& i, lexical_castable& le) {
  le.read_(i);
  return i;
}
```

Based on [document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html),

```
template<typename Target, typename Source>
  Target lexical_cast(const Source& arg);
```

> 1> Returns the result of streaming arg into a standard library
>   string-based stream and then out as a Target object.
>
> 2> Source is OutputStreamable
>
> 3> Target is InputStreamable

**Question1**> For User Defined Type (UDT), should the OutputStreamable or InputStreamable always have to deal with `std::string`? For example, given a class containing a simple integer as member variable, when we define the `operator<<` and `operator>>`, what is the implementation code looks like? Do I have to convert the integer as a string? Based on my understanding, it seems that UDT always has to deal with `std::string` in order to work with `boost::lexical_cast` and `boost::lexcial_cast` needs the intermediate `std::string` to do the real conversion jobs.

**Question2**> Why the return value of `operator<<` or `operator>>` in above code is not reference to `std::ostream&` or `std::istream&` respectively?

Comment: That the code does not return a reference is very likely a bug, since streams aren't copyable.

Comment: It is a bug that `lexical_castable::read_` is a const member function

Comment: It is a bug that `lexical_castable::print` includes a '\n'.

Answer (score 8):

To make your class usable with `lexical_cast`, just define the "stream" operators for it.
From [Boost.LexicalCast Synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html):

> - Source is OutputStreamable, meaning that an **`operator<<`** is defined that takes a **`std::ostream`** or **`std::wostream`** object on the left hand side and an instance of the argument type on the right.
> - Target is InputStreamable, meaning that an **`operator>>`** is defined that takes a **`std::istream`** or **`std::wistream`** object on the left hand side and an instance of the result type on the right.
> - Target is CopyConstructible [20.1.3].
> - Target is DefaultConstructible, meaning that it is possible to default-initialize an object of that type [8.5, 20.1.4].

:

```
// either inline friend, out-of-class friend, or just normal free function
// depending on whether it needs to access internel members
// or can cope with the public interface
// (use only one version)
class MyClass{
  int _i;
public:
  // inline version
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& ms){
    return os << ms._i;
  }

  // or out-of-class friend (friend declaration inside class only)
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& ms);

  // for the free function version
  int get_i() const{ return _i; }
};

// out-of-class continued
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& ms){
  return os << ms._i;
}

// free function, non-friend
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& ms){
  return os << ms.get_i();
}
```

The same of course for `operator>>`.

Comment: The OP is asking how lexical_cast over some types can be handled **without** the stringstreams in between.

Comment: @Kos: The OP asked if he had to use **strings** all the time.