# Is there a standard way to convert a class to a string

Tags: c++, c++11

In Java, the standard is to define the method `toString()` to return a string representation of a class.  Other than overloading `operator<<`, is there any such standard in C++?  I know there are the `std::to_string()` methods to get a string representation of a number.  Does the C++ standard speak of defining the method `to_string()` to serve similar purpose for a class, or is there a common practice followed by C++ programmers?

Comment: Seems like the structures that need a `toString()` method would be outweighed by those who don't. Just my opinion.

Comment: What do you want the effect of this '*standard*' method to be? In C++ there is no standard way to define a 'conversion to string' (which more often than not is not sensibly possible) and hence no standard way to request such a conversion.

Comment: Nothing stops you from providing to_string() overloads for your own classes (or making some own function/method with another name)

Comment: You could also write type conversion operator for std::string, but that is not very common.

Comment: This question: "other than the standard way, is there a standard way?"

Comment: no and no.  I use "std::string dump()" to provide state of object info in hex or tabular - typically for development.  I use "std::string show()" for use in the program context for user support.

Comment: `operator std::string() const;` fight me

Comment: Java has the advantage of using the same string encoding on all platforms -- not so much in C++. You'd have to have both a `toString()` and a `toWString()`, and exactly what encoding those returned would vary from platform to platform. It would be a major pain to support.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there was a paper on this [discussed at Kona](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/), I did not see this mentioned in the trip reports. Let me check STLs.

Comment: Thank you all for all your comment and insight.  I am not looking for for what such a method would do (as in what would go into the returned string), but more so, a "common" method name that is agreed upon (hence the standard).  If a class writer, decided to provide a method that returned a string representation of the class, at the least there is some sort of agreement on the method name (be it to_string, toString, etc).  I figured to_string would be a good choice, since the std already provides such methods for primitive integer types.

Comment: @AhmedA the operator would be the name of the member function `struct MyClass { operator std::string() const { return "MyClass"; } };` This would let you convert to string `MyClass mc; std::string s(mc);`

Comment: Based on your comment above, I edited the question to say, the question was about a standard 'name' for a method, rather than a standard way to implement the method. Also, could you please mark one of the answers as accepted, or post an answer yourself based on your comment above ?

Answer (score 15):

The standard way to do this kind of thing is to provide an *insertion operator* so that an object can be inserted into a stream -- which may be any kind of stream, such as a stringstream.

If you wish, you can also provide a method that converts to a string (useful for your insertion operator), and, if you find the conversion acceptable, you can provide a 'to string' operator.

Here's my standard 'point' class example:

```
template <typename T>
struct point
{
  T x;
  T y;
  point(): x(), y() { }
  point( T x, T y ): x(x), y(y) { }
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& outs, const point <T> & p )
{
  return outs << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
}
```

I also tend to keep a handy function around to convert things to strings:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string( const T& value )
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Now I can use it easily:

```
int main()
{
  point p (2,-7);

  std::cout << "I have a point at " << p << ".\n";

  my_fn_which_takes_a_string( to_string(p) );
```

You'll find that the [Boost Lexical Cast Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) is also designed for this kind of thing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard does not prescribe a way to do this but it looks like there is a proposal which may introduce such an option [Generic to_string/to_wstring functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0117r0.html) which says in the motivation section which also highlights the current common practices being taken(*which I demonstrate below*):

> For a long time C++ programmers have been looking for an easy way to
>   convert an object into its string representation. **A typical answer to
>   this problem was to create a local ostringstream, insert the object
>   into the stream, and then obtain the resulting string with the str
>   member function**. This solution is simple, safe, flexible and
>   extensible, though definitely too verbose for something that rather
>   ought to be a single function call. C++11 provided (a partial)
>   solution in the form of a set of overloaded to_string/to_wstring
>   functions. Unfortunately, these are limited only to the built-in
>   numeric types. **Non-standard solutions exist too – most notably
>   boost::lexical_cast, which offers two-way conversion of objects and
>   strings, but lacks any formatting control**.
>
> This paper proposes a solution that:
>
> - generalizes the existing to_string/to_wstring functions for any type that provides a stream output operator and for any basic_string
>     specialisation,
> - remains consistent and mostly compatible with these functions,
> - provides extra formatting and concatenation capabilities,
> - is conceptually simple by building upon the familiar ostringstream solution.

There are two trip reports [STL's](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/35g7f6/c17_progress_update/) and [Herb Sutter's](http://herbsutter.com/2015/10/25/2568/) and I don't see this paper mentioned in either. So hopefully this will be covered in the [post-Kona](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/) mailing when it comes out.

The first method they mentioned in the proposal would look something like [the example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549937/1708801):

```
class A {
public:
  int i;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const A &a) {
  return strm << "A(" << a.i << ")";
}
```

combined with the something similar to the example [from here](https://pbeblog.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/generic-stringstream-function-in-c/):

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& value) {
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << value;
  return os.str();
}
```

We can find a `boost::lexical_cast` example in the question [Enabling Classes for Use with boost::lexical_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8630451/1708801).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is no standard way. As I understand [C++ standard does not permit overloading of `std::to_string` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

I ended up using one of these two solutions:

#### Solution #1

Instead of toString() method you can use:

```
operator std::string() const {
    return "Object string.";
}
```

And to support streams you can add something like this:

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &out, const YourClass &obj) {
    return out << static_cast<std::string>(obj);
}
```

I hope that the `<<` operator will just inline the conversion from the first operator.

#### Solution #2

Or you can go other way if you think often in the stream-style:

```
friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &out, const YourClass &obj) {
    out << "Object ";
    out << "string.";
    return out;
}
```

And use it inside conversion operator:

```
operator std::string() const {
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << *this;
    return out.str();
}
```

Either way this get you covered for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the C++ standard speak of defining the method to_string() to serve similar purpose for a class,

No.

> or is there a common practice followed by C++ programmers.

No. However, I suspect every project has similar functionality. The name and return type most likely depend on the coding guidelines of a project.

At my work, we use

```
virtual QString toString() const = 0;
```

in one of our base classes.

You can start using something similar for your project.

```
virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
```

in your base class(es).

Answer (score 1):

In c++20 you can use `std::format` and specify custom formatter for structs and classes. An example taken from [here](https://www.heise.de/blog/Mehr-Details-zur-Formatierung-benutzerdefinierter-Datentypen-in-C-20-9638185.html):

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Point {
    int x{2017};
    int y{2020};
    int z{2023};
};

template <>
struct std::formatter<Point> : std::formatter<std::string> {
    auto format(Point point, format_context& context) const {
        return formatter<string>::format(
               std::format("({}, {}, {})", 
                           point.x, point.y, point.y), context);
  }
};

int main() {
    Point point;
    std::cout << std::format("{}", point) << '\n';
}
```

Note that your compiler's libstd++ implementation might not support `std::format` yet.